# Raising Authorization with ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, identityserver4

I have an ASP.NET Core (2.1) application using IdentityServer4, which the user upon login, receives a token that gives him accesses to some end-points, however there are others end-points that the user only has access after a "second login" (using a code for example).

Is there a way that I can generate a second token using the first one?

I'm looking to this http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/extension_grants.html?highlight=custom, and thinking to use some custom policy together with some claim.

But I'm not sure how to pass and validate the already generated token. or if has a better option.

Some similar solution would be very helpful.

Comment: The "code" you are mentioning here, is it validated in the IdentityServer4?

Comment: No, actually what I'm trying to validate, is the idea to "update" this primary token, with this other token.
If it's possible or even correct to do that

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to understand the principle of the authorization service and work with other services.
The primary token is what you got from the authorization service. It usually contains the logic to re-update the token, in case of obsolescence. The rest of your services will connect to the authorization service and check the user's data by token.
But do not forget - after the generation of the token, the user has Claims. They are stored in a user session. Each of the services receives the necessary information about the user without having to check each time a token and so on. All information is already stored in the user session.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to update the primary token in this scenario. Identity contained in the primary token should be static generally.

But I would override consent functionality provided by Identity Server to add the second validation step. This logic can be written depending on the client who requests authentication.